# What is in the hand of Castor? Can that be a mirror?

Tags: greek, interpretation, iconography

My question is about the twin brothers - the mortal Castor and the immortal Pollux. Regarding this statue, which is a Roman copy of a 4th-5th century BC Greek version:

[image]

In the descriptions I found it is usually only written that Pollux is holding two torches, while Castor a "disk". Can that disk be a mirror, through which he is looking at Pollux? Because there have been multiple antique circular mirrors found, which depict Castor and Pollux on their reverse side. For example this bronze Etruscan mirror, from 3rd century BC:

[image]

(If that was true, then one possible interpretation could be that Pollux represents the source of light, and Castor its reflection. Just like the Sun and the Moon.)

Comment: That these statues are Castor and Pollux is just a guess. There's nothing positively affirming their identity.

Comment: @cmw Yes -- there are a lot of claims this same statue is of Orestes and Pylades.

Comment: @Spencer thanks!